# Check an Excel Cell Data Type

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**Is it possible to determine the Data Type and Format of an Excel cell?**

I know there is `.NumberFormat` but it returns the formatting not the type...

I need to know if it's custom, then it should return custom, currency should return Currency and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood Excel stores values in a special way (most datatypes are actually doubles) and that makes it tricky to detect Cell Formats without the help of Excel.

Hence I recommend you leverage the inbuilt Excel `CELL` function rather that interrogating the datatypes yourself:

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //C1 is a cell I use to evaluate the Format of Cells A1 thru to A7
    using (var rnEvaluate = xlApp.Range["C1:C1"].WithComCleanup())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            rnEvaluate.Resource.Value2 = "=CELL(\"format\",A" + i.ToString() + ")";
            string cellFormat = GetExcelCellFormat(rnEvaluate.Resource.Value2);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(cellFormat);
        }
    } 
}

private string GetExcelCellFormat(string cellFormat = "G") 
{
    switch (cellFormat.Substring(0, 1))
    {
        case "F" :
            return "Number";
            break;
        case "C":
            return "Currency";
            break;
        case "D":
            return "Date";
            break;
        default :
            return "General";
            break;
    } 
}
```

ps The `.WithComCleanup()` is because I am using [VSTO Contrib](http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-contrib/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

That depends, if it is an xslx file (Open XML excel) then you can unzip the xlslx file (xlsx is a zip file) and check inside the xl\worksheets\sheet{?}.xml file for that particular cell.

That might be an overly complex way to do it though.

Comment: Its not overly complex if the tasks need to be done on a server, KB257757. Problem is with this method like mine the cell data type descriptions aren't complete, for example in XML the number cells dont specify decimal places: `<Data ss:Type="Number">` :(

Answer (score 0):

After getting the `NumberFormat` from the Excel range, you can convert it using [this table of formatting codes](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm), or [this reference from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx).  Keep in mind that mixed formats are possible if customized.

If you just want the base values (my defaults from drop down in Excel 2010):

- "0.00" - Number
- "$#,##0.00" - Currency
- "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??*);*(@_)" - Accounting
- "m/d/yyyy" - Short date
- "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy" - Long date
- "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM" - Time
- "0.00%" - Percentage
- "# ?/?" - Fraction
- "0.00E+00" - Scientific
- "@" - Text
- "General" - General

I got these values by recording a macro and modifying the number format for the selected cell.

---

**EDIT:**
A little more help to get where you want to go - assuming that you are using the Excel interop library (the only way I know how to access the `NumberFormat` function):

```
string fileName = @"c:\Book1.xlsx";
Application app = new Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
   Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Worksheet sheet = wb.Sheets[1];  //Change to the sheet you care about (1 based index)
var cell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];    //Change to the cell you care about (1 based index)
string cellNumberFormat = cell.NumberFormat; //Number format of cell to compare against known values
```

Setup for using the interop library found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel).

Comment: Also, feel free to change the accepted answer if you feel that the one you have marked isn't sufficient for your needs.

Comment: This doesn't answer it Jon, try the `NumberFormat` - it spits out "general" despite the cell being a Currency, Date or other format. The links dont help much either.

Comment: @Jeremy - See my edit above, when the cell number format has been set `NumberFormat` returns values previously mentioned and found in the links provided.

Comment: I think the confusion can be cleared up with this line from OP - "i know there is .NumberFormat but it returns the formatting but not the type..."