# Excel VBA: Find columns with dates, return column value if found

Tags: vba, excel

I'll keep it quick and honest, I am developing some code in order to find column references against peoples names if they have a financial figure associated with them.

Below I have a set of tables, one which outlines the original spreadsheet, and the other which is what I am expecting this code to do, i have written the code to find matching date entries on the two sheets, and return the column number of the date against the names which ONLY contain values.  The rest are ignored, however the code doesn't paste anything into column D as it shows below, and I get no errors.  The resulting entry against all the names always ends up being 16384, can anybody see any errors with my code?

See below for sheet examples and code.  Its worth noting that the original sheet is a pivot table.

```
                    Original Sheet
       A   |    B     |    C     |    D     |
  1________|__________|__________|__________|
  2________|__________|__________|__________|
  3________|__________|__________|__________|
  4________|__________|__________|__________|
  5        |01/01/2015|01/02/2015|01/03/2015|
   ________|__________|__________|__________|     
  6 henry  |   $200   |          |    $300  |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  7 luke   |   $100   |   $250   |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  8 michael|   $300   |          |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  9 james  |          |   $250   |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|


       Sheet with Column values where the original figures existed

       A   |    B     |    C     |    D     |
  1________|__________|__________|__________|
  2________|__________|__________|__________|
  3________|__________|__________|__________|
  4________|__________|__________|__________|     
  5________|__________|__________|__________|
  6 henry  |    2     |          |    4     |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  7 luke   |    2     |     3    |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  8 michael|    2     |          |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
  9 james  |          |     3    |          |
    _______|__________|__________|__________|
```

**Code begins here**

```
Sub MapValues
Dim namerow As Long, actualrow As Long, actualcolumnsource As Long, actualcolumntarget As Long
Dim actualcost As Range
Dim actualcostvalue As String
Dim J As Long
Set CapexSourceSheet = RngSource.Worksheets("Capex Pivot")
Set CapexTargetSheet = RngDest.Worksheets("Capex")

Set dumpsheet = RngSource.Worksheets.Add
dumpsheet.Name = "Dump Sheet"
dumpsheet.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
dumpsheet.Range("B1").Value = "Source Row Number"
dumpsheet.Range("C1").Value = "Target Row Number"
dumpsheet.Range("D1").Value = "Actuals"

'Set ranges and arrays for the find function
dumpsheet.Activate
namerow = CapexSourceSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
actualcolumnsource = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).row
CapexTargetSheet.Activate
actualcolumntarget = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

lngCnt = 2

' Loop takes the date from the original sheet, and checks the target sheet for the date 
' column, if it finds a match, it should return the column number.  Instead it returns
' nothing


CapexSourceSheet.Activate

For J = 1 To actualcolumnsource
       actualcostvalue = CapexSourceSheet.Cells(5, actualcolumnsource).Value
          CapexTargetSheet.Activate
            Set actualcost = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, actualcolumntarget).Find(What:=actualcostvalue, _
                                                                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                                      LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                                      MatchCase:=False, _
                                                                      SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not actualcost Is Nothing Then
            lngCnt = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
               Do While lngCnt > 0
               If actualcost.Value = CapexTargetSheet.Cells(5, actualcolumntarget).Value Then
                  dumpsheet.Cells(lngCnt, 4) = actualcost.Column
               End If
               lngCnt = lngCnt - 1
               Loop
            End If
            actualcolumnsource = actualcolumnsource - 1
Next J
```

**UPDATE**: The 'sourcename' variable can pick up the dates in the source sheet, but it cannot seem to find them in the target sheet.  In the source sheet, the dates are written in text, but in the target sheet the dates are not free text, they are formulas (example, 01/03/2015 is written as =+DATE(YEAR(AB5),MONTH(AB5)+1,1)) where the value in AB5 is 01/02/2015.  Could this affect the outcome in the .FIND method?

Comment: In you output, shouldn't you have the matching date as the header?

Comment: I don't because in the output, it is put into a sheet called "Dump Sheet".  This doesn't contain the date itself, it instead contains row and column references for the names and their respective dates so I can do a copy / paste command using column and row references for both the source and target sheets.  I would normally do this via an array, but both of the source and target sheets are not perfect data tables.  In short i'm dealing with badly designed data sets, therefore I have had to resort to this method to copy / paste characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and check if it helps you:

```
actualcolumntarget = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

OR

You use this method to get exact number of columns:
TO use this, set rw and cl variables.

```
rw = 1
cl = 1
Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, cl) <> ""
cl = cl + 1
Loop
```

Comment: That does help with returning the right number of columns, it changes it to 34, however I am still getting the value 34 rather than the column that contains values for its corresponding name.

Comment: This has got me on a track, I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

Better off using `UsedRange` instead of `.End(xlToRight).Row` and `.End(xlToRight).Column` and then iterating over the rows checking which columns have date values in the used range.

The method I use to check cell formats is `=Cell("format", A1)`. This will yield Date formats for actual dates. As I mention in the link below dont store dates as text becuse under the bonnet Excel uses Doubles, so you make it hard for yourself to detect if dates are or aren't numbers (without Excels help).

REF: [How to know the formatting of Excel Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778089/how-to-know-the-formatting-of-excel-cell)

Comment: I would agree, but not in this case.  The source spreadsheet is a perfect dataset (sorted in a pivot table), however this is not the case for the target spreadsheet which has names sorted in Column E, and dates across row 5, the names however are scattered across rows with gaps in between, and they start at row 528 instead of row 5.  I don't see how I could use usedrange in this case, especially considering the target sheet uses entire columns as section separators

Comment: Are those hardcoded values, **Row 528** and **Column E**? Doesn't really matter I guess, just letting you know my way of checking DataTypes/CellFormats in Excel and Dates can be very misleading.

Comment: Row 528 is the start point for the name checks, that part works, its the dates I have an issue with (actualcolumntarget)