# Range.Value produces different results in VBA and C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

I have noticed that Range.Value produces different results in VBA and C# for date values.

For example if a cell has value 5/13/1988 with NumberFormat d/m/yyyy, in VBA Range.Value will return "5/13/1988" whereas in C# it returns "5/13/1988 12:00:00 AM"

Range.Value2 is the same(32276) in both languages.

Does anyone know why VBA and C# are producing inconsistent results in this situation?

Note that I am aware that I could use a combination of Range.Value2 and Range.NumberFormat and then format the value in C#, but I am interested why the behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: Dates are simple 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899 with times being a decimal portion of a day. 12:00:00 AM (midnight) is .0 so they are expressing exactly the same thing. I don't find the results inconsistent at all.

Comment: agree with @Jeeped, `Format(cdate("5/13/1988"),"M.DD.YYYY HH:MM:SS")` will return the same `5.13.1988 00:00:00` result, so there is no inconsistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. In the Excel Interop (you ref in your VSTO project) MS have obviously mapped Date cell values to the  .Net DateTime data type.

Best choice for them, you wouldn't want to use like a Date .Net data type (remember VB classic only has Date data types not DateTime).

See how excel handles data under the hood here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983731

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net and C# Handle it differently.

**Excel 2013**

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**VB.Net 2013**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '~~> Opens an existing Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Delete Later\Sample.xlsx")

    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value)

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**C# 2013**

C# Unfortunately handles it like you mentioned.

[image]

You can do this to get the desired result

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible=true ;

        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(
                    "C:\\Users\\Siddharth\\Desktop\\Delete Later\\Sample.xlsx", 
                    0, true, 5, "", "", true, 
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 
                    "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        // Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        String cellvalue = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        MessageBox.Show(cellvalue);

        //
        //~~> Rest of the code
        //
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you saying that VB.NET & C# handle it differently? Both of them should output exactly the same Date to string conversion if the proper culture/format is being accounted for. VB.NET & C# should always behave identically and thus your first statement is quite misleading.

Comment: Yes they should handle it the same but it doesn't as I have demonstrated above :) `.Value` in both give different outputs...

Comment: Actually I wrote a first version of my comment which I deleted (the two displayed message boxes are not showing the same values?).  MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value) (and the VB.NET version) is a bad way to convert a date type (what Excel provides) into a string, as far as you are not having full control on what is happening. You should always account for the given culture and/or format (e.g., Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") below). Why it is different in your case? Perhaps both VB.NET/C# projects have different default culture. The outputs will be identical if you do it properly.

Comment: You are missing the point here. I am not converting but trying to show what the `.Value` in both cases hold. If you do not ant to use `MessageBox.Show`, use the quickwatch to see the difference :)

Comment: When you see a date as string in .NET there has occurred a conversion date type to string type; in this conversion a culture (and/or date format) has been accounted for. If you don't expressly specify it, the given language would take the default one (whatever it is). Thus, to have full control in the input/output process of any date/time to a .NET application, you should bring the culture into consideration, what you are not doing. Include the aforementioned date-format in both VB.NET & C# codes and the behaviour should be the same.

Comment: BTW long time since our last chat :) (as you can see, I am back!!)

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
// Put the following code before InitializeComponent()
// Sets the culture to US English
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
// Sets the UI culture too
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```