# Detecting Number Format Of Excel Cells With PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Does anyone know how to detect the format of Excel cells using PHPExcel? One answer here [How to know the formatting of Excel Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778089/how-to-know-the-formatting-of-excel-cell) did it in C#, but I want to do it with PHPExcel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1');
```

Will return the Style object for cell A1 in the current active worksheet. You can then look at the properties of the style object to identify the elements of style that you're interested in.

If it's specifically the number format, then

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat();
```

Will return the number format mask object, which has a `getFormatCode()` method to return the format mask as a string

**EDIT**

If you specifically want to test if a cell contains a date format mask or not, then there's a special built-in function specifically written for this purpose:

```
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row))) {
    echo 'Cell contains a date or time';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. yeah the problem is that there is no way for me to know beforehand the cell address. I wrote a wrapper that parses any worksheet but I discovered that cells with date formats are stored in integers in Excel, so I want to detect those so I can programmatically filter them and get their date before saving in DB. What I tried was `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col, $row ) );` but seems to be missing something,

Comment: Oh mine! That is exactly what I want. I'll test it right away. Many thanks.

Comment: Ah, every cell is seen as "General" I don't know why.

Comment: Are you loading the file with `setReadDataOnly` set to true? If so, then you're explicitly telling PHPExcel not to read the number format masks (or any other styling information)

Comment: Yes. Could that impact what I am trying to ?

Comment: The fact that you're telling PHPExcel not to read the number format masks will certainly impact, because any request to get a mask will then simply return the default

Comment: Works like charm!! A million thanks for your patience with inexperience. I can't thank you enough. Wish I could upvote as many times as I'd love to.

Comment: hello, i have the same problem $sheet->getStyle($cellId) always returns a phpexcel style where formatCode is always "General"; i used $objReader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007(); $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false); but with no success; can you please give me a clue to what i may be doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it possible that the cell format actually is set to "General"? But without knowing your file, I can't even begin to guess what it contains

Comment: it is a previously created file, in MS Excel, and i access it from PhpExcel; i checked in Excel and the cell is formatted as number percentage and has format code: 0%

Comment: but when i acces the style from PhpExcel, as written above, the formatCode is "General"; the reason i need to know if a cell is formatted as a percentage, is because i need to know when to divide the number the user entered in the Application form by 100 to write in the cell; how other i can write a percentage value in a cell using php excel, if not divide it by 100, because the user enters for example 49, but in Phpexcel i need to write 0.49, do you have any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: As a member of SO for 7 years, you should know that the way to ask a question isn't to comment on somebody else's question

Comment: PHPExcel should be reading the cell formatting correctly from an xlsx file unless you have specifically told it not to do so. The code that I posted in this answer should read the formatting mask that is applied to the cell, and a cell formatted as a percentage value should certainly not return "General" for the number format mask.

Comment: But without any code to see, or file to examine, I have no idea what you might be doing wrong