# Incorrect error data from excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am importing data from excel to mySql DB using OLEDB provider. When there is a field with %, it automatically get divided by 100. Let say I have 2 column Qty and Disc_Percentage with value 4 and 25%. When I got data from excel sheet to datatable, it convert Disc_Percentage value to 0.25.  I have below code for reading excel

```
 public static DataTable ConvertExcelFileDataToDataTable(string file, string extension)
            {
                var dtImportedData = new DataTable();

                // -- Start of Constructing OLEDB connection string to Excel file
                var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                // For Excel 2007/2010
                if (file.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
                    props["Extended Properties"] = "\"Excel 12.0\"";
                }
                // For Excel 2003 and older
                else if (file.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
                    props["Extended Properties"] = "\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes\"";
                }
                else
                    return null;

                props["Data Source"] = file;

                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
                {
                    sb.Append(prop.Key);
                    sb.Append('=');
                    sb.Append(prop.Value);
                    sb.Append(';');
                }

                //You must use the $ after the object you reference in the spreadsheet
                var conn = new OleDbConnection(sb.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                var myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataTable dtSerialNumbers = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                if (dtSerialNumbers == null)
                {
                    return dtImportedData;
                }

                var excelSheets = new String[dtSerialNumbers.Rows.Count];

                // Add the sheet name to the string array.
                if (dtSerialNumbers.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //we need the first sheet so save the first sheet name from the first row of the table
                    excelSheets[0] = dtSerialNumbers.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "]", conn);
                }

                myCommand.Fill(dtImportedData);
                dtImportedData.TableName = excelSheets[0].Replace("$", String.Empty);
                return dtImportedData;
            }
```

Comment: what is your question? IMHO this is absolut correct from a mathematical-POV:    25% of 20 = 20 * (25/100) = 5

Comment: Yes, But value should be 25% not 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

Excel(2016 on my machine) autodetects entered '%' and sets the cell-format to percent. I suggest reformating those cells before importing.

Comment: of course not, but but you can force a programm to do it ;) see this as an example on how to identify formatting [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778089/how-to-know-the-formatting-of-excel-cell)