IsError not capturing error returned by expression
What I am trying to do
I am trying to determine the first column in a named table that has a date.
What I have tried
Since all data in a table header row are stored as strings I figured I would have to first strip off the date numbers as a string, then convert them to a number, Then check if it is an error incase no numbers were in the pulled string.
My code to find the column of the table is as follows and blows up at the IF statement.
For Each HeaderCell In LO.HeaderRowRange
    If Not IsError(CLng(Left(HeaderCell.value, 4))) Then
        lngFirstDateCol = HeaderCell.Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next HeaderCell

I added each part of the check to the watch window.  HeaderCell.Value returns "Project No". Left returns "Proj".  CLng shows as a .  IsError shows as a .

My example header row looks like the following
Proj No | TTTT | Office | Staff | RFP | 2024/10/4 | 2024/10/11

With the Example header I would like to return the value of 6
Question
What is the right approach to finding The first column that is a date column?  Currently I have it hard coded.

FYI you cannot use IsError() to trap/suppress run-time errors - you'd need to use regular error handling for that.

@TimWilliams Thanks for the clarification on that.  As I am not a programming guru, I am assuming the proper method of error trapping has something to do with  On Error Resume Next or On Error Goto Something.  I am really not well versed on the proper syntax /  structure for that and need to learn it.

Use IsDate to validate the value.
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Long, bFound As Boolean
    For c = 1 To Columns.Count
        If IsDate(Cells(1, c)) Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If bFound Then
        MsgBox "The first date column (index) is " & c
        ' your code
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't locate date in the first row."
    End If
End Sub



Locate the first date col in ListObject header row.
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range, bFound As Boolean
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Set LO = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    For Each c In LO.HeaderRowRange
        If IsDate(c) Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If bFound Then
        MsgBox "The first date column (index) in LO is " & LO.ListColumns(c.Value).Index
        ' your code
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't locate date in the header."
    End If
End Sub



Don't forget you can use =CELL("format", A1) to get the format, eg   https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983731/495455

I was trying to avoid using IsDate because I thought the determination of a string was highly dependent on what the system date setting are.  Though I could be wrong.  Also in my case the named table header row or list object is actually in C13

I don't think you need to worry about the system date settings. Regardless of the settings, the date value in a cell is stored as a numeric value.

@ForwardEd I uploaded a script to locate the first date col in ListObject header row.

Except that the date in a table header row winds up getting stored as a string.  Otherwise I would be all over the date approach.

LO.ListColumns(c.Value).Index I was missing that too thanks!
